Running a script with only the libraries defined in virtual environment (venv)
I worked for some time on a script and now I would like to create a virtualenv for it, create requirements.txt, so when I deploy the script to the server, all the necessary libraries would be installed from the requirements.txt file and I would not need to install one library after another.
So, I created a venv (virtualenv .venv), activated it (. .venv/bin/activate), checked installed libraries in this newly created venv and got the following output:
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        24.0
setuptools 69.2.0
wheel      0.43.0

Alright, so now I assumed that if I run my script, it will break because there are missing libraries in this venv. However, the script all worked well. I assume it is because Python somehow found it installed elsewhere on my laptop and used those.
How do I force the script to run and use only the libraries installed within the venv, so I don't forget to add these libraries to the venv and when I move the script to the server, then everything would get smoothly installed from the requirements.txt?

You might want to try out to run your script in isolated mode with the -I flag.

By default python also import packages from the user site packages. This can be disabled with the -s flag
python -s script.py


Thanks - I am just wondering, I am using it with Scrapy which is run through this command: scrapy crawl spider_name - I don't directly run a python script. How can I test it out?

If you have installed Scrapy to a venv, it should also install all needed packages to that venv. So when you run Scrapy it should look for packages roughly in the order of 1. working directy 2. enviroment site packages 3. user site packages. Assuming the Scrapy installation is configured correctly, the import should never resolve to the user site packages, because all dependencies are present. I guess you could test it by deleting some dependant package from the venv and see where it resolves then. But, Im not super familiar with packaging so take this with a grain of salt...

No, I didn't install Scrapy to the venv. I installed Scrapy on my laptop, started a Scrapy project and then I wanted to put this Scrapy project to this newly created venv.

Then just which scrapy to see where it points to. At least with conda if you have a venv active, it will use the one from the venv.
